# Does `then` indicate a performance order when talk about a comparison?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I am learning this [book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=M64sDwAAQBAJ&pg=PR6&lpg=PR6&dq=%22spatial%20feature%20encoding%22%20random%20forest&source=bl&ots=gNQLyCV16o&sig=ACfU3U1ALP-HKyZWscuJkQiPpwqnz9PR8A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdv9_Mv7bjAhU-B50JHd3kAZUQ6AEwCHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22spatial%20feature%20encoding%22%20random%20forest&f=false) "Deep Learning and Convolutional Neural Networks for Medical Image Computing"

> On the other hand, CNN models have been proved to have much higher
>   modeling capacity, compared to the previous image recognition
>   mainstream pipelines, e.g., HAAR, SIFT, HOG image features followed by
>   spatial feature encoding, `then` random forest or support vector
>   classifiers. Given millions of parameters to fit during model training
>   (much more than previous pipelines), CNN representation empowers and
>   enables computerized image recognition models, with a good possibility
>   to be able to handle more challenging imaging problems. The primary
>   risk is overfitting since model capacity is generally high in deep
>   learning but often very limited datasets are available (that are with
>   good quality of labels to facilitate supervised training). The core
>   topics of this book are represented by examples on how to address this
>   task-critical overfitting issue with deep learning model selection,
>   dataset resampling and balancing, and the proper quantitative
>   evaluation protocols or setups.

[image]

`then` indicates that the author put "CNN models" (method_1), "the previous image recognition mainstream pipelines" (method_2) and "spatial feature encoding" (method_3) in the comparison.

the question is

in the modeling capacity perspective, does `then` indicate method_1 > method_2 > method_3 ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, then does indicate order.

> **Then** - (adverb) next or after that [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/then)

In this context, it just means that the thing before the *then* comes before the thing after the *then*.

> First, put on your socks, **then** put on your trousers, **then** put on your shoes.
>
> He ate some salad, then some beef, and then finally he had a swig of beer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. is the order method_1 > method_2 > method_3 what exactly what the author indicates by `then`?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the content to say for sure, but my interpretation would be: [HAAR, SIFT, HOG image features] -> [spatial feature encoding] -> [random forest or support vector classifiers].

Comment: It's unusual for there to not be a conjunction before *then*. At least stylistically, I'd interpret the sentence as being *HAAR, SIFT, HOG, or image features, followed by spatial feature encoding **and** then random forest or support vector classifiers*. The use of *and* in this sentence would have avoided some of the confusion that's being caused by its absence.

Comment: @Jason +1 I would agree that it would be clearer if the author specified. I think they are probably assuming the reader knows a lot about the subject matter